# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Grid with Allow Selection (Genexus)

Tags: runtime-error, selection, genexus

Im having this problem that I couldn't find a way to solve. I have a dynamic grid with the allow selection option in true ant I have filters that if they changed the grid is reloaded and maybe has less rows than before. The problem occurs when I had selected a row, for example number 10 and then I reload the grid and only has for example 4 rows. When I try to put "Apply" (wich aplies the filters and reloads the grid)  it sends the famous "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException". This is because it remembers the last line selected. Is there any way to clean that? To forget the line that was selected?

Im using GeneXus X Evolution 1 version 10.1.32504 U2.5

Here is the error trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9 >= 6
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.GXObjectCollectionBase.elementAt(GXObjectCollectionBase.java:424)
    at com.si.ayc.aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.strup8N0(aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.java:1008)
    at com.si.ayc.aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.start8N2(aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.java:305)
    at com.si.ayc.aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.executeStartEvent(aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.java:137)
    at com.si.ayc.mpprincipalayc_impl.start042(mpprincipalayc_impl.java:216)
    at com.si.ayc.mpprincipalayc_impl.ws042(mpprincipalayc_impl.java:225)
    at com.si.ayc.mpprincipalayc_impl.webExecute(mpprincipalayc_impl.java:56)
    at com.si.ayc.aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.webExecute(aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43_impl.java:110)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectBase.doExecute(GXWebObjectBase.java:177)
    at com.si.ayc.aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43.doExecute(aycampliacionesgeneralpaso1_43.java:21)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(GXWebObjectStub.java:44)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(GXWebObjectStub.java:18)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.serveRequest(InvokerServlet.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet.doPost(InvokerServlet.java:170)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:157)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:190)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:283)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:767)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:697)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:889)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:690)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thank you for reading and trying to help.

Manuela

Comment: it also happends in the pagination if the last page has, for example less than 10  rows and the row selected was number 10

Comment: I didn't find a solution. I changed the way of doing what I wanted to do. Now I use a checkbox (&check) in each line to know if its selected or not and I use de &check.Click event to control that only one is selected, I unselect the one that was before. Also use de Load event to set the &check value to each line. Only put true in the line that is selected (i keep that index, set it on the &check.Click event)

Comment: It seems like a bug... please contact support so they can add an issue. Anyway, maybe setting `Grid.AllowSelection` to `false` before the `Refresh`, and back to `true` afterwards, solves your problem. Didn't try it though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats a good idea to try! I cant try it right now since I change everything already but next time I'll try it. Thanks